# Does typescript support web components?

Tags: typescript, web-component

I been reading up on web components and thought they are amazing so I jumped into my preferred work space(vs code, typescript 2.4.2) but it seems it doesn't support web components, or they are partly supported? the HTMLElement type definition contains a read-only field labeled: 'shadow root" but this is null by default and the HTMLElement type def doesn't have the method: create shadow root() so I'm not sure if I'm doing this wrong or something if I am could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If Javascript supports them, Typescript should. May be a browser limitation.

Comment: Well, that's what I thought. I've got the latest typescript version and call but their es6 definition file simply doesn't have the necessary methods for me to create a **ShadowRoot**. And I can't find any tutorials for web components and typescript other than react and angular stuff(which I am is not interested in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typescript supports web components. Method `createShadowRoot` is not in the typings because it was deprecated and removed from actual spec. You can read more about this method on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/createShadowRoot). You should use `attachShadow` method instead.

Comment: Yes i have found that method but the document definition is missing the **registerElement()** method as well.

Comment: That's because it also is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/registerElement). You should use `customElements.define()` instead.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your help